# Where is the /catkin_ws/src/ folder

Tags: ros, catkin, catkin.workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the tutorial here http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_urdf to clone the file into  /src folder, while I cannot find any src folder. Catkin has already been installed with ROS, so the workspace should be there I guess?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274248/where-is-the-/catkin_ws/src/-folder/) by [xj yang](https://answers.ros.org/users/32409/xj-yang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2017-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are supposed to make the workspace yourself first.

See [wiki/catkin/Tutorials/Creating a workspace for catkin](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace).

And note: the path is not `/catkin_ws`, but `~/catkin_ws`. The first is an absolute path in the root of your FS, while the second is a sub directory of your home directory.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xj yang](https://answers.ros.org/users/32409/xj-yang/) on 2017-10-26**:
Thank you!